# Leading whitespace on console.log when reading from process.stdin

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm attempting to build a CLI that takes input piped in via stdin and does some processing on it. Eg.

```
command1 | node my-cli.js
```

For some reason, I am unable to correctly parse the input without introducing a weird issue where subsequent calls to console.log generate increasing amounts of whitespace in the terminal.

I'm tried using both `readline` and `process.stdin.on('data')` but both are exhibiting this behavior.

```js
process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
  const line = chunk.toString();
  // console.log(line)
  console.log('hi');
});
```

Produces the following input when I try and pipe the command through the script

```
hi
hi
  hi
    hi
      hi
        hi
          hi
            hi
              hi
                hi
                  hi
                    hi
                      hi
                        hi
                          hi
                            hi
                              hi
                                hi
                                  hi
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out where this extra white space is coming from.

This doesn't happen in all cases, just everytime I pipe `command1` (which happens to be a tool called [pg_prove](https://pgtap.org/pg_prove.html) in this case). This leads me to believe that the underlying command is also homehow buffering something to be written but I can't understand why it happens for this but not when piping other CLI tools through my script.

Comment: `console.log('hi\r')` should maintain correct carriage position between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut is telling me that is some strange behavior that ignores the CRLF (Carriage Return;Line Feed) needed in the new lines.

`console.log` likely inserts a new line. If the position of each log is consistently incrementing its indent by whatever number of characters were previously logged. Then we've found the issue!

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar